# how to get a value from a python code to a Javascript variable in JS file

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to develop the frontend in Javascript for a voice bot, which was written in python

```
if hi == 0:
    talk('hello iam kavi')
    print('hello iam kavi Voice assistant')
    talk('How are you buddy!!!')
    print('How are you buddy!!!')
    talk('doing good right?????')
    print('doing good right?????')
```

In the code above, instead of printing it on the terminal, I want it to be sent to Javascript code, which looks like below

```
class MessageParser {
  constructor(ActionProvider, state) {
    this.actionProvider = ActionProvider;
    this.state = state;
  }

  parse(message) {
    const lowerCaseMessage = message.toLowerCase()
    
    if (lowerCaseMessage.includes("hello")) {
      this.actionProvider.greet();
    }
    else{
      this.actionProvider.listening();
    }
  }
}

export default MessageParser;
```

where the printed text in the python code should be sent as message variable into parse(message) function.

I'm a beginner at Javascript and React, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should first create some REST API logic, which makes communication possible between React and Python.

Comment: Depending on your tech stack and requirements [CGI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html) could be the most simple option. No need for an additional backend server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build an API in Python, to send the data to React. The fastest way will probably be using flask, it could look like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/talk', methods=['GET'])
def talk():
    return talk("whatever")
```

Then from react you can get the message using `fetch`, `axios` or any other option in the `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` depending on your needs. Please, note that I don't know how your `talk` function works so you'll have to adapt the code to send the correct message to the frontend.